# In a switch case statement, it says "duplicate case value" comes up as an error. Anyone know why?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, dev-c++

I am working on a rock paper scissors program, but this time the computer chooses rock half the time, scissors a third of the time, and paper only one sixth of the time. The way I did this was I enumerated six possible computer choice values:

```
enum choicec {rock1, rock2, rock3, scissors1, scissors2, paper};
choicec computer;
```

But then, after the computer makes its choice, I have to convert these enumerated values to either rock, paper, or scissors. I did this using a switch-case statement:

```
switch(computer) {
        case rock1 || rock2 || rock3:
            c = 1;
            break;
        case scissors1 || scissors2: //ERROR!
            c = 3;
            break;
        case paper:
            c = 2;
            break;
    }
```

one is rock, two is paper, and three is scissors. However, on the line where I have error written in as a comment, it gives me this error: [Error] duplicate case value.

I'm not sure why.
Any ideas?

Comment: `rock1 || rock2 || rock3` evaluates to true (1), like `scissors1 || scissors2`. You need separate labels, but can use fall-through, `case rock1: case rock2: case rock3: c = 1; break;`.

Comment: You can't use `||` in `case` statements.  Sorry :(

Comment: Wouldn't it have been a better design to have chosen an enum like `{ rock, scissors, paper }`, and then simply structured your random number generator to provide the necessary statistical percentiles?

Comment: thanks guys! that was all really helpful. now the program works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure what you doing, but switch statement should look like this

```
switch(computer) 
{
    case rock1:
    case rock2:
    case rock3:
        c = 1;
        break;
    case scissors1:
    case scissors2:
        c = 3;
        break;
    case paper:
        c = 2;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't use `||` in `case` branches.  Sorry :(
When you use `||` it does a logical or on them, that says "is `rock1` or `rock2` or `rock3` not a zero?".  And the answer is yes, at least one of those is not zero.  So `rock1 || rock2 || rock3` is `true`, which is `1`.  And `scissors1 || scissors` is also `true`, which is `1`.  So you have two `case` branches for the `1` case.

You should simply use `case` fallthrough to select multiple conditions:

```
switch(computer) {
    case rock1: case rock2: case rock3:
        c = 1;
        break;
    case scissors1: case scissors2:
        c = 3;
        break;
    case paper:
        c = 2;
        break;
    default:
        std::cerr << "INVALID COMPUTER MOVE";
}
```

Also, I always have a default in my case switches.  Sometimes mistakes happen, and we definitely want to know if it doesn't hit any of the case branches.  I'm also pretty paranoid about missing `else` statements, but about half the time it's ok if there's no `else`.

Answer (score 4):

That `switch` statement does not do what you think.

Each `case` defines **one** value that the value of `computer` is matched against. Combining several values with logical disjunction to give the value associated with a single `case` label does **not** make the corresponding block be entered when the value of `computer` is equal to *any* of those values, but rather when it is equal to the result of their logical OR combination. Not very meaningful, indeed.

This is how you could rewrite your `switch` statement in order to make more sense:

```
switch(computer) {
    case rock1: // Is it rock1?
    case rock2: // Or perhaps rock2?
    case rock3: // Or maybe rock3?
        c = 1;  // Well, if it's one of the above, do this...
        break;
    case scissors1: // OK, it wasn't. So is it scissors1?
    case scissors2: // Or scissors2?
        c = 3;      // If it's one of the above, do this...
        break;
    case paper: // So is it paper?
        c = 2;
        break;
    default: // Always better to be explicit about this
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
switch(computer) {
    case rock1:
    case rock2:
    case rock3:
        c = 1;
        break;
    case scissors1:
    case scissors2:
        c = 3;
        break;
    case paper:
        c = 2;
        break;
}
```

`rock1 || rock2 || rock3` and `scissors1 || scissors2` are both expressions which evaluate to "true", hence the conflict.

Answer (score 2):

The expression used in the switch statement must be integral type ( int, char and enum). In the Switch statement, all the matching case execute until a break statement is reached and Two case labels cannot have the same value.

But in the above case with logical or condition.
At first 
`case: rock1 || rock2 || rock3:`
This will evaluate to 1 and second `case scissors1 || scissors2:` will also evaluate to 1. This is cause error as said **Two case labels cannot have the same value.**

This is the reason compiler complains and giving an error:

`Compiler Error: duplicate case value`

To solve this convert to

```
switch(computer) {
        case rock1: 
        case rock2:  
        case rock3:
            c = 1;
            break;
        case scissors1:
        case scissors2: //Now will not give any error here...
            c = 3;
            break;
        case paper:
            c = 2;
            break;
    }
```